# Create super user working, create normal user not (Django)

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Made a custom user model, a serializer for each users data and a manager. When imported breakpoint while making a superuser function was executed and password that i gave the superuser was hashed and added in the database. When i tried adding a normal user in database function was not executed and django was not using my UserProfileManager at all. Normal user was created but not using my Model or Manager

serializers.py

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
"""Serializes a user profile object"""
class Meta:
    model = models.UserProfile
    fields = ('id', 'email', 'name', 'password')
    extra_kwargs = {
        'password':{
            'write_only': True,    
            'style':{'input_type':'password'} 
        }
    }

def create(self, validated_data):
    """Create and return a new user"""
    user = models.UserProfile.objects.create(
        email=validated_data['email'],
        name=validated_data['name'],
        password=validated_data['password']
    )

    return user
```

Comment: How did you implement your API?

Comment: I registered my custom urls, in the projects urls(so when i start app /profile is a route for creating new profiles). I have the UserProfile model, and the above is the manager for it, so i dont understand why is super user created sucessfully and password is hashed but create_user is not recognized at all. I hope this explanation helps, django is a new thing for me.

Comment: can you share the view that is creating the `UserProfile` and `User`?

Comment: I added it above instead of the first code i sent.

Comment: @kovaceviccp please see the [Editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn more about formatting your post. Also share your serializer

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Well you call the `create` method not the `create_user` method... Also please see [ask], you keep changing the code you show in the question and remove other code that was also relevant. See how to write a [mre].